# Is it possible to return a value from a Julia function after throwing an error?

Tags: julia

I want to be able to both throw both an error but still be able to get a value returned.

So what I've tried are the following two, but neither seem to behave the way I want them to:

```
function func()
    try
        error()
    catch e
        throw(e)
    finally
        return 10
    end
end
```

This returns a `10`, but doesn't throw errors.

```
function func()
    try
        error()
    catch e
        throw(e)
    finally
        10
    end
end
```

This throws an error but doesn't return a 10.

***Note:*** I get the same results as the second bit of code without using a finally

What I would want is to be able to call `foo = func()`, have the error get thrown and have `foo = 10`

Comment: That is not how exceptions work. You either get the return value or the exception (which unless caught bubbles up through not just the immediate caller but all of them). Maybe you want to return a pair of values (with both the `10` and an error code)?

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not want to do that.  You likely want to return two values, 
the second an error, as Thilo said above:

```
function func()
    err = ""
    try
        error()
    catch e
        err = "Error string"
    finally
        10, err
    end
end

foo, errstring = func()
```

There is a way to do what you should probably not do. 
Use a global for foo, and assign to the global in the function 
instead of via the return value, as in:

```
foo = 2

function func()
    global foo = 10
    try
        error()
    catch e
        throw(e)
    finally
        10
    end
end


function thrower()
    try
        func()
    catch
        println("foo = $foo")
    end
end

thrower()
```